# Does C# have an equivalent to JavaScript's encodeURIComponent()?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, windows, encoding

In JavaScript:

```
encodeURIComponent("©√") == "%C2%A9%E2%88%9A"
```

Is there an equivalent for C# applications? For escaping HTML characters I used:

```
txtOut.Text = Regex.Replace(txtIn.Text, @"[\u0080-\uFFFF]",
    m => @"&#" + ((int)m.Value[0]).ToString() + ";");
```

But I'm not sure how to convert the match to the correct hexadecimal format that JS uses. For example this code:

```
txtOut.Text = Regex.Replace(txtIn.Text, @"[\u0080-\uFFFF]",
    m => @"%" + String.Format("{0:x}", ((int)m.Value[0])));
```

Returns "`%a9%221a"` for `"©√"` instead of `"%C2%A9%E2%88%9A"`. It looks like I need to split the string up into bytes or something.

Edit: This is for a windows app, the only items available in `System.Web` are: `AspNetHostingPermission`, `AspNetHostingPermissionAttribute`, and `AspNetHostingPermissionLevel`.

Answer (score 282, accepted):

`Uri.EscapeDataString` or `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` is the correct way to escape a string meant to be part of a URL.

Take for example the string `"Stack Overflow"`:

- `HttpUtility.UrlEncode("Stack Overflow")` --> `"Stack+Overflow"`
- `Uri.EscapeUriString("Stack Overflow")` --> `"Stack%20Overflow"`
- `Uri.EscapeDataString("Stack +  Overflow")` --> Also encodes `"+" to "%2b"` ---->`Stack%20%2B%20%20Overflow`

Only the last is correct when used as an actual part of the URL (as opposed to the value of one of the query string parameters)

Comment: The main issue I was having was not having a reference to System.Web in my solution, but I wasn't aware of EscapeUriString, thanks!

Comment: In contrast to encodeURIComponent(), Uri.EscapeUriString() doesn't encode "+" to "%2b". Use Uri.EscapeDataString() instead.

Comment: Use WebUtility instead of HttpUtility to avoid having to reference System.Web. HttpUtility doesn't exist in .NET Core.

Comment: @Steve Would you consider making your last paragraph bold? It seems to be the most important thing to know on this page, and it needs more visibility.

Comment: Also see this answer for more explanation on the difference between Uri.EscapeUriString and Uri.EscapeDataString: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396598/whats-the-difference-between-escapeuristring-and-escapedatastring

Comment: See this answer for more explanation on the difference between HttpUtility.UrlEncode and HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145823/httpserverutility-urlpathencode-vs-httpserverutility-urlencode

Comment: `UrlPathEncode` and `EscapeUriString` do not encode ampersand `&` but `Uri.EscapeDataString` and `HttpUtility.UrlEncode()` do

Comment: Kudos to Steve for providing this excellent answer and Tim for the edited version. This work well and save my nerves after a very long search. To all of you who always contribute to this very useful platform, I say thank you!

Comment: `EscapeUriString` has been marked as absolete starting from .NET 6 because it can corrupt the Uri string in some cases. Use `EscapeDataString` instead. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/syslib-diagnostics/syslib0013

Answer (score 22):

`HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` / Decode
`HttpUtility.UrlEncode` / Decode

You can add a reference to the `System.Web` assembly if it's not available in your project

Comment: I should've been more specific: This is for a windows app, the only items available in System.Web are: AspNetHostingPermission, AspNetHostingPermissionAttribute, and AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.

Comment: You can add a reference to the System.Web assembly

Comment: HtmlEncoding is an entirely different thing. UrlEncode is a non-sensical API which should never be used. It doesn't make sense to encode an entire URL (unless you actually want to encode its value to use as a parameter - but that's not what this does). The point of encoding/escaping is that you're conveying that a reserved character should be passed through without its usual meaning (e.g. that ? identifies the query, or & separates query parameters). This requires knowledge that UrlEncode does not and cannot have.

Answer (score 21):

I tried to do full compatible analog of javascript's encodeURIComponent for c# and after my 4 hour experiments I found this

c# CODE:

```
string a = "!@#$%^&*()_+ some text here али мамедов баку";
a = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(a);
a = a.Replace("+", "%20");
```

the result is:
**!%40%23%24%25%5e%26*()_%2b%20some%20text%20here%20%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%20%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2%20%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%83**

After you decode It with Javascript's decodeURLComponent();

you will get this: 
**!@#$%^&*()_+ some text here али мамедов баку**

Thank You for attention

Comment: Works, but you can simply use `Uri.EscapeDataString("!@#$%^&*()_+ some text here али мамедов баку")` instead.

Comment: Actually, `Uri.EscapeDataString` encodes the characters '(' and ')' while `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` does not.

Answer (score 15):

System.Uri.EscapeUriString() didn't seem to do anything, but System.Uri.Escape**Data**String() worked for me.

Answer (score 10):

Try `Server.UrlEncode()`, or `System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode()` for instances when you don't have access to the `Server` object. You can also use `System.Uri.EscapeUriString()` to avoid adding a reference to the `System.Web` assembly.

Comment: Uri.EscapeUriString() didn't do anything for me, but I was able to properly url-encode the strings using Uri.EscapeDataString()

Comment: @TolandHon: Indeed. The reason is that `Uri.EscapeUriString()` corresponds to JavaScript's `encodeURI()` - which preserves URI-reserved chars. such as `/`, `&`, ... as-is (plus `#`), whereas - as you've discovered, it is `Uri.EscapeDataString()` that corresponds to JavaScript's `encodeURIComponent()`.

Answer (score 10):

For a Windows Store App, you won't have HttpUtility. Instead, you have:

For an URI, before the '?':

- System.**Uri.EscapeUriString**("example.com/Stack Overflow++?")

  - -> "example.com/Stack%20Overflow++?"

For an URI query name or value, after the '?':

- System.**Uri.EscapeDataString**("Stack Overflow++")

  - -> "Stack%20Overflow%2B%2B"

For a [x-www-form-urlencoded](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1) query name or value, in a POST content:

- System.Net.**WebUtility.UrlEncode**("Stack Overflow++")

  - -> "Stack+Overflow%2B%2B"

Answer (score 6):

You can use the Server object in the System.Web namespace

Server.UrlEncode, Server.UrlDecode, Server.HtmlEncode, and Server.HtmlDecode.

Edit: poster added that this was a windows application and not a web one as one would believe.  The items listed above would be available from the HttpUtility class inside System.Web which must be added as a reference to the project.

Comment: The Server object is inaccessible from a windows app