# mailto link multiple body lines

Tags: html, outlook, mailto

having trouble getting multiple lines to work correctly in a mailto link

In my case I'm testing it with an Outlook default mail reader.

The following is put in an anchor href:

`mailto:email@address.com?&subject=test&body=type%20your&body=message%20here`

only "message here" shows up in the email body. (whether I use chrome or IE)

thoughts?

Answer (score 240, accepted):

You can use [URL encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) to encode the newline as `%0A`.

`mailto:email@address.com?subject=test&body=type%20your%0Amessage%20here`

While the above appears to work in many cases, user olibre [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27447222/834528) that the RFC governing the mailto URI scheme specifies that `%0D%0A` (carriage return + line feed) should be used instead of `%0A` (line feed). See also: [Newline Representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations).

Comment: Thanks, this worked well for me and seems much simpler than other solutions floating around on the internet.

Comment: This should work for all special characters, right? &=%26, %=%25, are there any characters where this pattern doesn't hold?

Comment: for info, `$0A` is simply `escape( "\n" )`

Comment: That encoder uses the standard `encodeURIComponent` to encode the URI components.

Comment: %0D%0A Worked for me for email and share in whatsapp message

Comment: I've been trying to use this to do a double line break, whenever I use 2  `%0D%0A` together it breaks the hyperlink

Answer (score 46):

1. **Use a single `body` parameter** within the `mailto` string
2. **Use `%0D%0A` as newline**

The [`mailto` URI Scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto) is specified by by [RFC2368](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2368) (July 1998) and [RFC6068](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6068) (October 2010). 
Below is an extract of [section 5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6068#section-5) of this last RFC:

> [...] line breaks in the body of a message MUST be encoded with `"%0D%0A"`.
> Implementations MAY add a final line break to the body of a message
> even if there is no trailing `"%0D%0A"` in the body [...]

See also in [section 6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6068#section-6.1) the example from the same RFC:

```
<mailto:infobot@example.com?body=send%20current-issue%0D%0Asend%20index>
```

The above `mailto` body corresponds to:

```
send current-issue
send index
```

Answer (score 20):

To get body lines use escape()

```
body_line =  escape("\n");
```

so

```
href = "mailto:me@my.com?body=hello,"+body_line+"I like this.";
```

Comment: I prefer this personally. Mainly because this also works when you try and add a %

Comment: `encodeURIComponent`, rather. [See here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/best-practice-escape-or-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent)

Answer (score 18):

This is what I do, just add `\n` and use `encodeURIComponent`

Example

```
var emailBody = "1st line.\n 2nd line \n 3rd line";

emailBody = encodeURIComponent(emailBody);

href = "mailto:me@somesite.com?body=" + emailBody;
```

Check [encodeURIComponent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53273283/react-conditional-rendering-inside-component-return-function) docs

Comment: What `include` do you use for `encodeURIComponent` ?

Comment: @frakman1 encodeURIComponent is a JavaScript function. You can use it without any includes.

Comment: @Koosh bcoz the above code is JavaScript, try this method to encode email body in Blazor https://stackoverflow.com/a/4550600/1188322