# How to inject a draft message into Thunderbird from another program?

Tags: email, thunderbird, mbox

I have my own application which generates messages to be saved in the **Drafts** folder of Thunderbird. Actually, I just append to the **Drafts** file, but it doesn't seem right to open a file Thunderbird already has opened.

As a result, Thunderbird doesn't realise that there are new messages in the **Drafts** folder, and of course the **Drafts.msf** file isn't current. After closing and restarting Thunderbird, the new messages show.

**My question is now:** Is there a better way to provide drafts to users? Just triggering Thunderbird to re-read the **Drafts** file and rebuild the .msf index would be fine, I think.

Right now I am doing this on Linux, is there anything specific if I want to do the same on Windows?

I don't want to use the **-compose** on the command line, because it would open too many windows when I insert a lot of draft messages.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mailto: Body formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11507387/mailto-body-formatting)

Comment: Nope, far away! I dont't want to create a link which can be clicked manually to pop up a compose mail window. Nor do I want to call "thunderbird -compose" to pop up a mail window automatically. I want to inject a message including pictures into the drafts folder which later can be opened and amended by users before being sent off.

Answer (score 0):

If case you don't mind creating an add-on for Thunderbird to do this:

Thunderbird add-ons can react to custom command line arguments, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Chrome/Command_Line for more details.

In the add-on you could then either insert the e-mail to the draft folder or trigger the re-read of the Drafts file.

Comment: Of course I wouldn't mind creating an add-on, if only there was some documentation about it without lots of warnings that most of it is outdated. I have been unable to find any documentation about an API telling how to trigger the re-read of a file like the Drafts folder.

Comment: Yes, the Thunderbird development documentations is rather bad. The API for a folder in described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIMsgFolder. i havened tried it, but updateFolder may be right function to use. If that doesn't work you could use the rebuildSummary function: https://mxr.mozilla.org/comm-central/source/mail/base/content/folderPane.js#2075. This is the one used to repair the .msf file.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, my solution to the problem is unrelated to Thunderbird. Instead of fiddling with Thunderbird, I communicate directly with the IMAP server to write a new draft mail into the "Drafts" folder.

Thunderbird (or other clients, for that matter) picks up the new draft mails and the user can handle them.