# New line in plain text anchor tag

Tags: email, outlook, whitespace, plaintext

I see various posts that a new line in plain text mails are added by using \r\n in double quotes, and all examples related to is using it programmatically.

I am looking for a way to do the following from text saved in a text column in a database field as shown below (simplified).

```
<a href="mailto:me@my.com?subject=Wrapped Up&body=
Enter our competition below.

Name:
Surname:
Email:

Good luck!">
    Click here to enter our competition!
</a>
```

The goal is to have the white space preserved in the plain text mails. I tried \r\n, \n, \r, and Outlook ignores me.

Any idea what else I can add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you know how to search what you are looking for, the answer is possibly out there. This solved my problem:

[mailto link multiple body lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10356329/mailto-link-multiple-body-lines/)