# \n is removed from my email body

Tags: html, email, uri, mailto

I am using JavaScript to formulate a `mailto:` URI, but for some reason the `\n` characters are not working.

My string is constructed like this:

`var emailBody = "This is the first line!\n" +
                 "This is the next line.\n" +
                 "And so on and so forth.\n";`

And then I form a URL like:

```
var mailToLink = 'mailto:' + emailTo
               + '?subject=' + emailSubject
               + '&body=' + emailBody;
```

and instruct the browser to navigate to that URI:

```
var win = window.open(mailToLink, 'emailWindow');
```

My email client opens with the draft email in the window, but all the "lines" are displayed consecutively. I see no line breaks, except those rendered due to the email client's natural word wrapping.

How can I generate this email with the newline characters intact?

Comment: How is that string being converted from a JavaScript data structure to the content of the email?

Comment: Is your email HTML formatted? In which case you would need to use `<br />`

Comment: _Completely_ depends on lots of things we can't see. I for one have never heard of emails being generated by JavaScript.

Comment: I am using the window.open(mailToLink, 'emailWindow');

Comment: I create a variable: mailToLink =  'mailto:' + emailTo + ?subject=' + emailSubject + '&body=' + emailBody;

Comment: Would <br /> work instead of \n?

Comment: @Chris — No. Your email isn't HTML formatted.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sorry if I misspoke. I am using JavaScript to call the mailTo: function. Very handy to create emails on the fly!

Comment: Okay well that is not really JavaScript!!!

Comment: I have fixed the question, and found that it is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/10356329/560648.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit very eloquent edit! How would I mark this a duplicate, I feel some of the answers are not as straight forward as Quentin's answer, but the encodeURIComponent is among the comments of some answers, so a dup this is indeed.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I create a variable: mailToLink = 'mailto:' + emailTo + ?subject=' + emailSubject + '&body=' + emailBody;

You can't have a literal new line in a URL.

You should generate your query strings using `URLSearchParams` instead of mashing strings together. That will take care of any escaping that needs to be done.

```js
const emailTo = "example@example.com";
const emailSubject = "Visit a café";
const emailBody = `This is a body which includes
a new line!`;

const url = new URL(`mailto:${emailTo}`);
url.searchParams.set('subject', emailSubject);
url.searchParams.set('body', emailBody);

var mailToLink = url.toString();
console.log(mailToLink);
```

---

2015 answer:

You should pass each value through [the `encodeURIComponent()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) when adding it to the URL string (which will take care of all characters with special meaning including new lines, `+`, `%` and so on).

Comment: ABSOLUTE GENIUS! Worked like a charm! I am very pleased, because I don't see any answers like this anywhere else on Stack! Take your correct and upvote, good Sir.