# Why is line break with HTML mailto not working in yahoo mail?

Tags: html, mailto, yahoo-mail

I have used `%0D%0A` for line break. It is working in many email clients, but it is not giving line break in yahoo email. Why? Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Please share related code

Comment: `href='mailto:$emailId?subject=$taskStr&body=Task* : %0D%0APriority* : %0D%0AStart Date* : %0D%0ADue Date* : %0D%0AAssigned To* : %0D%0ADescription : %0D%0A'` is the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mailto link multiple body lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10356329/mailto-link-multiple-body-lines)