# react - conditional rendering inside component return function

Tags: reactjs

I would like to understand why react behaves this way.

This works

```js
class Feed extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const posts = [{ id: 1, title: 'post-1' }, { id: 2, title: 'post-2' }];
    return (
      <>
        {posts.map(post => (
          <Post key={post.id} title={post.title} />
        ))}
      </>
```

But this doesn't

```js
class Feed extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const posts = [{ id: 1, title: 'post-1' }, { id: 2, title: 'post-2' }];
    return (
      <>
        {posts.map(post => {
          // changes are here
          if (post.id < 2) {
            <Post key={post.id} title={post.title} />;
          }
        })}
      </>
```

It just returns blank. No errors.

What is the reason react isn't rendering this? And what would be the best approach to only render `post-1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arrow function syntax can accept either a value to return, or a block of code to execute. In the first example, you give a value: `<Post key={post.id} title={post.title} />`. However, in the second example you give a code block (by using {}). So, you need to either add `return` before `<Post key={post.id} title={post.title}>`like so:

```
{posts.map(post => {
  if (post.id < 2) {
    return <Post key={post.id} title={post.title} />;
  }
})}
```

or change the if into an && to keep the implicit return behavior:

```
{posts.map(post =>
  (post.id < 2) && <Post key={post.id} title={post.title} />
}
```

Comment: It makes sense now. I was always omitting the second return statement. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2):

You have to change it to `return <Post ... />;`

Answer (score 2):

You didn't **return** anything in the `map` function argument. You can do that easily with a **ternary expression and using es6 arrow notation**:

```
 posts.map(post => (post.id < 2) ? <Post key={post.id} title={post.title} /> : null)
```

Comment: The ternary expression you used is incorrect. Please check my edit

Answer (score 1):

The second didn't work because you forgot the `return` statement.

Try this:

```
  <>
    {posts.map(post => {
      // changes are here
      if (post.id < 2) {
        return <Post key={post.id} title={post.title} />; //added return statement
      }
    })}
  </>
```