# Using various inputs of a form in mailto-body

Tags: html, css

I'm helping someone set up a website, and we're limited to only CSS and HTML. No JavaScript, PHP, or other tools.

We're setting up a simple `mailto:` form (knowing very well this is old and obsolete), and part of it is working fine. Setting the subject with `name="subject"` and the body with `name="body"` allows submitting the text-input and the textarea-input to Outlook from a submit-button.

Now, we're trying to add a dropdown list to the form, so the user can choose the type of request to be handled, adding this to the body of the mail; but have no clue as to how to do this without recurring to a third language.

**tl;dr:** How to append a string to a GET form without adding a new & in raw HTML?

Any help will be appreciated.

This link provides some guidance as to how the link *should* look, setting each form input to a new line of the body parameter: [mailto link multiple body lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10356329/mailto-link-multiple-body-lines)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That can't be done.

If you're going to process the data from the form you need a language other than css and html.

HTML & CSS are simple languages. They aren't able to process information, rather they are instructions which are processed by the browsers.

You will need some kind of traditional/scripting language if you're going to retrieve & work with the data from the web-form.