# How can I get line feed character into a PChar string

Tags: delphi

I am using ShellExecute to invoke the local Email client and populate the mailto Address, Subject and Body in the Email Client.  This is the code I have used...

```
  HdrBdy := 'mailto: support@positonstudio.co.uk' +
                '?Subject=Test Message Subject' +
                '&Body=Positron Studio ' + fmIDEAbout.lblIDEVersion.caption +' '+ fmIDEAbout.lblBuildTarget.caption + #13+
                 CompInfo.SystemManufacturer + ' Model No. ' + CompInfo.SystemProductName  +#13+
                 'Processor ' + CompInfo.ProcessorName + ' OS Version ' + OSInfo.Description  +#13+
                '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------';

  ShellExecute(Self.Handle,
               nil,
               PChar(HdrBdy),
               nil,
               nil,
               SW_NORMAL);
```

This works but the body text appears as a single line in the Email client. How can I insert multiple lines in the Mail client.

Comment: what version of Delphi you are using?

Comment: `#13` is a carriage return. `#10` is a line feed.  Depending on who is consuming the text, a line feed may be expected as the termination character for a line.

Comment: Delphi 10.4.1  - I have tried all combinations of #10 #13, the text appears in the Client in a single line.

Comment: Needs to be URL encoded so ends up as `%0D%0A`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10356329/mailto-link-multiple-body-lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are nearly there, you need to have both carriage return and linefeed.

So instead of `+#13+` you need `+#13+#10+` or you can use `+#13#10+`

I suspect that you will also then need to Percent Encode the string that's set to the Body value to pass it properly in the URL.

You can use `TURLEncoding.Encode()` for this.

```pascal
HdrBdy := 'mailto: support@positonstudio.co.uk' +
                '?Subject=Test Message Subject' +
                '&Body='+TURLEncoding.Encode('Positron Studio ' + fmIDEAbout.lblIDEVersion.caption +' '+ fmIDEAbout.lblBuildTarget.caption + #13#10+
                 CompInfo.SystemManufacturer + ' Model No. ' + CompInfo.SystemProductName  +#13#10+
                 'Processor ' + CompInfo.ProcessorName + ' OS Version ' + OSInfo.Description  +#13#10+
                '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------');
```

Comment: Instead of ``#13#10`` you can use the constant ``sLineBreak``

Comment: @DelphiCoder sLineBreak is not guaranteed to be #13#10 on all platforms - in fact the docs say specifically that it's #10 on Linux. For normal mail messages I _think_ the RFCs say line endings _should_ be CRLF.  It does seem as though the environment is Windows (ShellExecute) so I admit that the distinction is academic.