# C# How to retrieve an original string from the UTF-8 string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, encoding

on my page I have set the UTF-8 encoding. Then, I send a string "`ły`" encoded by [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) function to `%C5%82y` and on the server side, I get `%25C5%2582y`. And now I want to have back the original string.

I've tried:

```
HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(): the result is %25C5%2582y
Uri.UnescapeDataString(): the result is %C5%82y
```

I'm confused now - how to retrieve back the original string ?

Comment: How do you get "#C5#82y" from `encodeURIComponent`?

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86477/does-c-sharp-have-an-equivalent-to-javascripts-encodeuricomponent

Comment: This looks like a double-encoding, where the `%` in `%C5` is encoded as `%25`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Uri.UnescapeDataString(HttpUtility.UrlDecode("ły"));
```

done the trick

Comment: You can probably also do any of these twice, like `Uri.UnescapeDataString(Uri.UnescapeDataString("%25C5%2582y"))`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` to encode and `HttpUtility.UrlDecode` to decode.