# Replace {x} tokens in strings

Tags: c#, asp.net, token

We have a template URL like:

```
http://api.example.com/sale?auth_user=xxxxx&auth_pass=xxxxx&networkid={networkid}&category=b2c&country=IT&pageid={pageid}&programid=133&saleid=1&m={master}&optinfo={optinfo}&publisher={publisher}&msisdn={userId}
```

and I have values for these constant tokens. How can replace all these tokens in C#?

Comment: Look up `string.Replace` on msdn.

Comment: is this url you want to store somewhere and send it or is it coming in your request???

Comment: possible duplicate of [Named string formatting in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159017/named-string-formatting-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Side note on example URL: when using http instead of https for the url then the url is sent unencrypted. Thus if someone is sniffing your traffic, he can see the username and password in the url (and it may be logged in server logs on the way).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A simple approach is to use a `foreach` and a `Dictionary`  with a `String.Replace`:

```
var values = new Dictionary<string, string> {
    { "{networkid}", "WHEEE!!" }
    // etc.
};
var url = "http://api.example.com/sale?auth_user=xxxxx&auth_pass=xxxxx&networkid={networkid}&category=b2c&country=IT&pageid={pageid}&programid=133&saleid=1&m={master}&optinfo={optinfo}&publisher={publisher}&msisdn={userId}";

foreach(var key in values.Keys){
    url = url.Replace(key,values[key]);
}
```

Comment: Nice way to borrow my replacement value ;-) Well, it is pretty simple to understand, so +1.

Comment: This algorithm runs slowly in time O(t * r) and will give incorrect results if one of the replacement values contains a token for later replacement. [Details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71826824/145173)

Comment: @EdwardBrey, this is feature, not a bug :-D

Comment: @Grundy That's funny because it's kind of true. Applying replacements recursively can be useful. To be clear, that would take a more sophisticated algorithm, one that rescanned for replacements as a second complete pass (and then again with subsequent passes until no replacements were left), to avoid missing recursive replacements occurring late in the template. It would also need to check for infinite recursion.

Comment: @EdwardBrey, for now, here not a recursion, just one way replacing in loop by keys. Any way this just as simple as possibly solution :) Straight replacement without any regexp

Comment: It depends on the replacement values. For example, suppose `optinfo` is `excludeFromReceipt:{publisher},{userId}`, `publisher` is `Acme`, and `userId` is `14`. With successive full-string replacements, you'd get ...`&optinfo=excludeFromReceipt:Acme,14&publisher=Acme&msisdn=14` instead of ...`&optinfo=excludeFromReceipt:{publisher},{userId}&publisher=Acme&msisdn=14`.

Comment: Also worth noting is while, yes, using string.Replace is simpler in that it doesn't use Regex, it has its own complexity that a Regex-based approach avoids. Specifically, using string.Replace requires you manage your own iteration and variable mutation. Using Regex shields you from both making it simpler to prove correctness for all input cases.

Answer (score 9):

There is no standard way to "replace with dictionary values" in .NET. While there are a *number* of template engines, it's not very hard to write a small solution for such an operation. Here is an example which runs in [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) and utilizes a [Regular Expression with a Match Evaluator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy(v=vs.110).aspx).

As the result is a URL,
it is the callers responsibility to make sure all the supplied values are [*correctly encoded*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/86477/2864740). I recommend using [`Uri.EscapeDataString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring(v=vs.110).aspx) as appropriate .. but make sure to not double-encode, if it is processed elsewhere.

Additionally, the rules of what to do when no replacement is found should be tailored to need. If not-found replacements should be eliminated entirely along with the query string key, the following can expand the regular expression to `@"\w+=({\w+})"` to also capture the parameter key in this *specific* template situation.

```
string ReplaceUsingDictionary (string src, IDictionary<string, object> replacements) {
    return Regex.Replace(src, @"{(\w+)}", (m) => {
        object replacement;
        var key = m.Groups[1].Value;
        if (replacements.TryGetValue(key, out replacement)) {
            return Convert.ToString(replacement);
        } else {
            return m.Groups[0].Value;
        }
    });
}

void Main()
{
    var replacements = new Dictionary<string, object> {
        { "networkid", "WHEEE!!" }
        // etc.
    };
    var src = "http://api.example.com/sale?auth_user=xxxxx&auth_pass=xxxxx&networkid={networkid}&category=b2c&country=IT&pageid={pageid}&programid=133&saleid=1&m={master}&optinfo={optinfo}&publisher={publisher}&msisdn={userId}";
    var res = ReplaceUsingDictionary(src, replacements);

    // -> "http://api.example.com/sale?..&networkid=WHEEE!!&..&pageid={pageid}&..
    res.Dump();
}
```

More advanced techniques, like reflection and transforms, are possible - but those should be left for the *real* template engines.

Comment: A simplified Regex-based algorithm that takes replacements as strings is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71826824/145173).

Comment: @EdwardBrey Indeed. Looking at the code above 5 years later, it appears I was still stuck on C#5 at the time.. many language improvements since.

Answer (score 5):

I am guessing you are trying to replace parameters in `url` with your values. This can be done using C# `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString`

Get the CurrentURL from

```
   var _myUrl = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.RawUrl);
```

Read Parameter from your Query string

```
   string value1 = _myUrl ["networkid"];
```

Write a value into the QueryString object.

```
  _myUrl ["networkid"] = "Your Value";
```

and then finally turn it back into URL

```
  var _yourURIBuilder= new UriBuilder(_myUrl );
 _myUrl = _yourURIBuilder.ToString();
```

Comment: does this handle url encoding?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this alos using LinQ

```
Dictionary<string, string> myVal = new Dictionary<string, string>();

myVal.Add("networkid", "1");
myVal.Add("pageid", "2");
myVal.Add("master", "3");
myVal.Add("optinfo", "4");
myVal.Add("publisher", "5");
myVal.Add("userId", "6");

string url = @"http://api.example.com/sale?auth_user=xxxxx&auth_pass=xxxxx&networkid={networkid}&category=b2c&country=IT&pageid={pageid}&programid=133&saleid=1&m={master}&optinfo={optinfo}&publisher={publisher}&msisdn={userId}";
myVal.Select(a => url = url.Replace(string.Concat("{", a.Key, "}"), a.Value)).ToList();
```

this line can do your required functionlity

**myVal.Select(a => url = url.Replace(string.Concat("{", a.Key, "}"), a.Value)).ToList();**

Answer (score 2):

There is a Nuget called StringTokenFormatter that does this well
https://www.nuget.org/packages/StringTokenFormatter/

Comment: Excellent package for this task.

Comment: It has URI processors built in, do you know if this handles url encoding automatically?

Answer (score 1):

`Regex.Replace` makes a single pass over a template string, offering you an opportunity to replace matched expressions. Use it by creating an regular expression that matches any token. Then look up replacement values for the tokens in a dictionary.

```cs
static string ReplaceTokens(string template, Dictionary<string, string> replacements) =>
    Regex.Replace(template, @"{(\w+)}",
        match => replacements.TryGetValue(match.Groups[1].Value, out string replacement) ? replacement : match.Value);
```

The algorithm completes in time linear with the size of the template string and the replacement strings, so O(t + r). Beware of algorithms that make multiple passes. They run slowly in time O(t * r) and will give incorrect results if one of the replacement values contains a token for later replacement. This unit test shows the pitfall:

```cs
public void TestReplaceTokens() {
    var replacements = new Dictionary<string, string> {
        ["Movement"] = "drive {DontReplace}",
        ["DontReplace"] = "Should not appear"
    };
    string withReplacements = ReplaceTokens("I always {Movement} in {Direction}.", replacements);
    Assert.AreEqual("I always drive {DontReplace} in {Direction}.", withReplacements);
}
```