# How to format string using input parameter and not placeholders

Tags: c#

So, I want to format a string using input parameter and not the index placeholders. Preferably I would like to use a `Dictionary`. but I am not sure how to implement it.

```
var str = "I have {Bal} coins";
dictionary.Add("Bal", 20); 
var output =
```

**Expected Output:** I have 20 coins.

I can use String format like below:

```
var str = "I have {0} coins";
var output = String.Format(str, 20);
```

My requirement is such that I need to use *Dictionary*.

Comment: how about string interpolation using the [dollar sign](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does $ mean before a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31014869/what-does-mean-before-a-string)

Comment: You could maybe create a method that takes a `FormattableString` and your dictionary. The former is like an interpolated string (same syntax) but if the method accepts that type it doesn't actually format the args, but rather let's you inspect the string and the format parameters and format it yourself.. That is if `$"I have {dictionary[“bal"]} coins"` doesn't suffice

Comment: @pinkfloydx33: I am sorry I could not follow you. Is there any way I can use dictionary and be able to insert the values.

Comment: Sure you can, even without using a 3rd party library, you can just resort to `StringBuilder.Replace` like in this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36759694/is-there-a-string-format-that-can-accept-named-input-parameters-instead-of-ind

Comment: Do you need it to be dynamic, is the text with the placeholders provided by something other than code?

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "I have {0} coins";
var output = String.Format(str, 20);
```

you can use :

```
var output = $"I have {variable} coins"; // variable can be dictionary or other
```

read this post for more : [$ in C# string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31014869/what-does-mean-before-a-string)