# Convert pattern string to Interpolated string with dollar sign

Tags: c#, string-interpolation

```
var pattern = getPattern(); //read from the config, something like "{x} abc {y}"

var x = $pattern; //not compiling
```

Is there a way to convert a pattern in string Interpolated string?

Comment: Strings are interpolated at compile time. What you request is just not possible

Comment: `string.Format(pattern, x, y)`

Comment: The naming interpolated string may be the problem here so that you think that what you try is possible. It is rather interpolated **literal** string. It works on string literals not on strings as such.

Comment: You might be interested in a library like [SmartFormat.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36759806/2791540) which could do this for you at run-time.

Comment: You will need to use what @T.S. wrote. And instead of `"{x} abc {y}"` something like `"{0} abc {1}"`. When you do `$"{x} abc {y}"` you are getting the values right there and placing them in the string, you can't just convert a `"{x} abc {y}"` string to magically get the values from the current scope like in your code. What if there's no `x` or no `y`? It would make no sense.