# Equivalent to Javascript's encodeURI?

Tags: c#, .net, urlencode, encodeuricomponent

C#'s equivalent to **encodeURIComponent** is [well-covered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86477/does-c-sharp-have-an-equivalent-to-javascripts-encodeuricomponent) on SO and elsewhere, but what about **encodeURI**? Basically I want to encode *[invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547899/which-characters-make-a-url-invalid)* URL characters only and not *reserved* characters such as `/`, `:`, etc. So

```
"http://www.example.com/my cool page"
```

would be encoded to

```
"http://www.example.com/my%20cool%20page"
```

Is there something baked into .NET to do this? Or is a regex my best bet?

Comment: (Do note the subtle differences between the *many methods* presented in the linked question.)

Comment: Please do not close this question. This is not a duplicate of the encodeURI**Component** question; I tried to make that distinction clear in my first sentence.

Comment: There's nothing *baked into .NET*, it depends on what framework you're using.  ASP.NET, .NET 4.5, Portable Library, etc...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
Uri.EscapeUriString("http://www.mysite.com/my cool page")
```

Comment: This is the most portable method

Comment: Bingo, that's what I was looking for. HttpUtility.UrlEncode (and the like) encode the whole thing, ie `http%3a%2f%2fwww.mysite.com%2fmy+cool+page`, which isn't what I was after. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Server.URLEncode(uri.ToString)
```

Comment: Isn't this specific to ASP.NET?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode(String)
```

For example:

```
var url_encoded_string = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(userInput);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(string value)`.

Comment: Available in .NET 4 and later (works in Windows Store)