# is there a way of escaping the [] square brackets in the URL before invoking the Web SErvice API URL call?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, url, httpwebrequest, square-bracket

All:

There is an Bible ASP.NET Web Application that I am implementing. 
Within the Bible ASP.NET Web Application, I invoke the following Third-party web service API url:

https://bibles.org/v2/passages.js?q[]=john+3:1-5&version=eng-KJVA

Within in the ASP.NET Web Application, I have the following code:

```
String populatedPassagesEndpointUri = "https://bibles.org/v2/passages.js?q[]=john+3:1-5&version=eng-KJVA";

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(populatedPassagesEndpointUri);

request.Headers[System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("APIToken") + ":" + "X"));

request.Method = "GET";


String test = String.Empty;

using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())

{

  Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

  StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

  test = reader.ReadToEnd();

  reader.Close();

  dataStream.Close();

}
```

If you analyze the Web Service API url that I use above, you will notice that it uses [] square brackets which I believe is a bad practice to use within URLs:

https://bibles.org/v2/passages.js?q[]=john+3:1-5&version=eng-KJVA

Sadly, it's the third-party who provides the Web Services API, so I can't do anything about it.  I'm forced to use the URL with []

In any case, I executed the code above in my Bible ASP.NET Web application.
However, the above Webservice api URL invocation gives me a 401 error.
Does that have something to do with the [] square brackets in the URL?
If yes, is there a way of escaping the [] square brackets in the URL before invoking the Web SErvice API URL call?

Comment: Presumably you'd use one of the `UrlEncode` methods.

Answer (score 2):

You should use this

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode()
```

You code will become

```
String populatedPassagesEndpointUri = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("https://bibles.org/v2/passages.js?q[]=john+3:1-5&version=eng-KJVA");
```

to encode the url of your request.

Similar question on SO

1. [Url with square brackets in webClient.DownloadString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25271682/url-with-square-brackets-in-webclient-downloadstring)
2. [Are square brackets permitted in URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40568/square-brackets-in-urls)

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is not the URL, is the authentication method you are using.

> the above Webservice api URL invocation gives me a [401 error](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E401.html)

401 error means you failed on authentication.

I tried the URL you provided. It does accept Basic authentication, but I doubt the format you provide.

From your code, you are saying that your basic authentication **username** is Some **API token** , and your password is **X or something**. Seems not right.

The realm your server return is **ABS API** , and the error message I got is

> Authorization Required
>
> You must provide an API token or a username and password to access
> this page.

So I guess you should use token based authentication since you got an APIToken from your config file , not a useranme and password.

The way to do token authentication is various.

It could be something like

```
https://bibles.org/v2/passages.js?q[]=john+3:1-5&version=eng-KJVA&token=your API token
```

Or passing the token in authentication header like

```
Bearer yourAPItoken
```

Overall, you need to double check your authentication method,try to find some document about your website or ask for support form the website.

**Update:**

The reason of you getting 401 error is because your original request get redirected, and your authentication header will not survive redirection.

You need set your httpWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false , and test the respond code, if = 302 found, create a new request to the redirect location.

This may help you http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/49243/Handling-Cookies-with-Redirects-and-HttpWebRequest

Comment: I just briefly browsed your website. Try remove your authentication header and change your URL like this format 'https://#{your API token}:bibles.org/v2/passages.js?q[]=john+3:1-5&version=eng-KJVA'

Comment: I sent an email to their support email address ( digitalministry@americanbible.org ).  Let's see what they say.

Comment: `https://#{your API token}:bibles.org/v2/passages.js?q[]=john+3:1-5&version=eng-KJVA` doesn't work for you?

Comment: try this`request.Headers[System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes("#{" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("APIToken") + "}" + ":" + "X"));`

Comment: If you look at my code, I've already done all that.  Here is what I have request.Headers[System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("APIToken") + ":" + "X"));   No need for "#{" and "}" because other Web Service API urls provided by the third-party provider work with the Basic authorization code that I placed in this comment.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my own implementation, you can modify it to suite your needs:

Firstly, inject IHttpContextAccessor into the class where you are trying to implement this code;

Then utilize my code below, to suite what you want to achieve:

```
        var request = _httpConAccessor.HttpContext.Request;

        var builder = new UriBuilder();
        builder.Scheme = request.Scheme;
        builder.Port = request.Host.Port.GetValueOrDefault();


        builder.Path = "/Home/ConfirmEmail";
        var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(builder.Query);
        query["userId"] = user.EmailAddress;
        query["token"] = user.ActivetionCode.ToString();
        builder.Query = query.ToString();
        string link = builder.ToString();

        var link2 = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(link);

        return link2;
```

The output to this function looks like this for me:

```
https://localhost:44330/Home/ConfirmEmail?userId=myemailaddress@gmail.com&token=b5867906-7ede-44yd-adrt4-0272a5cacd
```

instead of

```
https://[localhost:44330]/Home/ConfirmEmail?userId=myemailaddress@gmail.com&token=b5867906-7ede-44yd-adrt4-0272a5cacd
```

Observe that the square brackets are absent.

Happy Coding.