# error 400 bad request Angular 5 login with token

Tags: asp.net, angular, access-token

my service is:

```
 getToken(){
    var data = "grant_type=password&username=" + "username" + "&password=" + "yTX7W0s1zYxbJJT3+pXtJA==";

return this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:51643/token', data).pipe(map(res =>res))
}
```

for this example I use username e password static
and in my componet

```
constructor(private data: PostaserviceService) { }
  ngOnInit() {  
     this.data.getToken().pipe().subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
    });
}
```

I have this error :
POST http://localhost:51643/token 400 (Bad Request)
ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 400, statusText: "Bad Request", url: "http://localhost:51643/token", ok: false, …}

Comment: Any logs in ASP.NET about the 400?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem was that I can't pass the special characters ==

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. They should be OK after the initial = that separates key and value, or you could try encoding them as %3D (i.e. [encode as an URL component](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4550600/243245)). But if it works without, great. Sorry I didn't spot that back then!